# Computing A, B given A+K and B+K

Tags: cryptanalysis

In his [writeup](https://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html) of the Solitaire keystream generator algorithm, Bruce Schneier warns not to use the same key for two different messages:

> The first rule of an output-feedback mode stream cipher, any of them,
>   is that you should never use the same key to encrypt two different
>   messages. Repeat after me: NEVER USE THE SAME KEY TO ENCRYPT TWO
>   DIFFERENT MESSAGES. If you do, you completely break the security of
>   the system. Here's why: if you have two ciphertext streams, A+K and
>   B+K, and you subtract one from the other, you get (A+K)-(B+K) =
>   A+K-B-K = A-B. That's two plaintext streams combined with each other
>   with no key involved, and is very easy to break. Trust me on this one:
>   you might not be able to recover A and B from A-B, but a professional
>   cryptanalyst can. This is vitally important: never use the same key to
>   encrypt two different messages.

Intuitively, this makes sense, but as he said, I'm not able to recover A and B.

What sort of attack is he talking about?

Comment: depending on the plaintext involved, you can perform lots of analysis on A+B, such as showing that they are ASCII text (low bit always 0) or there are overlapping letters (octet = 0x00), and using possible known blocks of A to recover B without any knowledge of B.

Comment: See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse/2250#2250 for one possible answer; this specific example uses 'exclusive or' rather than modular addition, the same principle applies

Comment: The answers to [What is the difference between a stream cipher and a one-time-pad?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/810/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stream-cipher-and-a-one-time-pad) and [How does one attack a two-time pad (i.e. one time pad with key reuse)?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/how-does-one-attack-a-two-time-pad-i-e-one-time-pad-with-key-reuse/2250#2250) should cover this.